# AzureAD GraphAPI: How to get Group-Name

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I try to get the group-memberships of a user via MS Graph API for Java.

My user is member in 7 groups. But I only get the group ID (sort of UUID) but displayName is always null.

Any idea how to get the name of the group??

```
User usr = gsc.users (MYUSERID).buildRequest ().get ();
System.out.println ("User: " + usr.displayName);
        
DirectoryObjectCollectionWithReferencesPage doc = gsc.users (MYUSERID).memberOf ().buildRequest ().get ();
java.util.List <DirectoryObject> lst = doc.getCurrentPage();
for (int i = 0; i < lst.size (); i ++)
{
    if (lst.get (i) instanceof Group)
    {
        Group gp = (Group) lst.get (i);
        System.out.println ("Member: " + gp + " / " + gp.id + " / " + gp.displayName);
    }
}
```

Output is

```
User: MyTestUser
Member: com.microsoft.graph.models.Group@c514b123 / 83091123-c2ea-4883-8a2b-faab7de7433 / null
...
```

**EDIT**

This also only delivers null.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lst.size (); i ++)
{
   System.out.println (((Group)doc.getCurrentPage().get(i)).displayName);
}
```

**EDIT**

Changed to memberOfAsGroup - still null for displayName.

```
GroupCollectionPage doc = gsc.users (this.azureuserid).memberOfAsGroup ().buildRequest ().get ();
java.util.List <Group> lst = doc.getCurrentPage ();
for (int i = 0; i < lst.size (); i ++)
{
  Group gp = lst.get (i);
  System.out.println(i + "  Member: " + gp + " / " + gp.id + " / " + gp.displayName + "  " + gp.description);
}
```

Comment: I'm a C# guy, but I think your problem is your cast to `<DirectoryObject>`. If you change it to `Group` you should get what you want, cause the JSON response contains this information.

Comment: doc.getCurrentPage returns a List <DirectoryObject>

I added more output the my sample, but displayName is still null.

Comment: I'm not the Java guy. But according to the [code](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/blob/faa64e1bf8db3307e85b3493c9f9274917052450/src/main/java/com/microsoft/graph/requests/UserRequestBuilder.java#L266) I would guess there is also something like `gsc.users(userId).memberOfAsGroup()` that should return what you need.

Comment: I tried it and also put it in the EDIT of my question. Still null for displayName :-(

Comment: I got it going now - will post the solution in my question. Issue was Azure permissions, not software.

Comment: About your permission issue: If you defined application permission, the consent can only be given by the administrator for the whole organization. This granted set of permission is stored in your app service prinicpal. If you afterwards change the needed permission of the app, the grant is still valid and works. To revoke it, another consent grant must be given on the new set of permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is working now. Registered app in Azure needs permission for Groups.ReadAll (Application, not Delegate!).

Surprisingly not the assigned permission is needed but only the admin-consent to it - even if the persmission is removed.

Do not know if this is a bug or feature.